# Getting a nil crash even though the value isn't nil

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm trying to populate a collection view with data so I'm doing things like this:

```
cell.userImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: user[indexPath.row].imagePath))

cell.nameLabel.text = user[indexPath.row].username
cell.userID = user[indexPath.row].userID
```

These are all throwing errors saying that the value is nil, but I am printing these values right before the lines of code and the values are not nil.

I populate the user dictionary with this:

```
let userToShow = User()

if let username = value["username"] as! String?, let imagePath = value["urlToImage"] as! String? {

    userToShow.username = username
    userToShow.imagePath = imagePath
    userToShow.userID = uid
    self.user.append(userToShow)
    print(userToShow)
}
```

And the User class looks like this

```
class User: NSObject {

    var userID: String!
    var username: String!
    var imagePath: String!

}
```

I'm not really sure how these optionals work in swift so maybe I'm not declaring something the right way.

Comment: I'm not sure where the error is thrown at exactly, but try to replace `if let username = value["username"] as! String?` with `if let username = value["username"] as? String`

Comment: how you create the `self.user` array? You need first create an empty array, then perform `append` method.

Comment: Force casting into an Optional makes no sense. That will never have a `nil` value. Do `if let username = value["username"] as? String` instead if you want an `Optional<String>` as your output.

Comment: @Muli I changed it to that and it's still throwing an error at the set image. it's saying it's nil, but I'm printing it directly before that line and it's showing a valid string. Why would it encounter nil if there is a valid string there?

Answer (score 1):

There are two serious issues which both can cause the crash:

1. **Never** declare properties in a class as implicit unwrapped optional as an alibi not to write an initializer. Either declare them as non-optional with an initializer

   ```
   class User: NSObject {

       var userID: String
       var username: String
       var imagePath: String

       init(userID: String, username: String, imagePath: String) {
           self.userID = userID
           self.username = username
           self.imagePath = imagePath
       }
   }
   ```

   or as regular optional

   ```
   class User: NSObject {  
       var userID: String?
       var username: String?
       var imagePath: String?
   }
   ```

   By the way do you really need a class – even inheriting from `NSObject` – and do you really need `var`iables?
2. Force unwrapping an optional to an optional (`value["username"] as! String?`) sounds illogical and is very bad practice. Don't do that. The correct *optional binding* syntax is

   ```
   if let username = value["username"] as? String
   ```

Please read the section about [Optionals](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330) in the Swift Language Guide

Comment: thank you for the resource, I'll check it out. I'm using the class for better readability. At least I think that's why. I'm following a tutorial and they do not get this error.

anyways, do you have an idea why the variable is saying it's nil even though I'm printing it the line before and seeing it's non-nil? It's very strange.

Comment: I mean you could use a more light-weight **struct** rather than a class. Maybe the  behavior is related to something asynchronous? And which line are you talking about?

Comment: I removed a line where it says self.user.removeAll() and now it works. I didn't show that line though. Any reason why that line would cause a nil value when it's clearly there if it prints?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how `user` is declared and what `self.user.removeAll()` is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

In my retrievePosts() function I had a line that says self.user.removeAll(). I guess this was causing the dictionary to be deleted when I go to create the cell.

Comment: You guess, or did you actually verify this?

Comment: it was working for a day with only that change made, but now I am back at it not working. I do not know the cause of the bug. Should I delete the answer?

Comment: If it is not a correct answer, yes go ahead and delete it. It could confuse future readers.